# Single word for what happens to an algorithm when it is hacked

Tags: single-word-requests

"I coded an algorithm for making the system secure, but my classmate with his amateur hacking skills _____ it in just seven minutes."

"What happened that day was an algorithmic _______ (breakdown??)"

Which appropriate words complete the sentences, to imply that he hacked/decrypted/broke it down?

Comment: An algorithm doesn't get "hacked".  An algorithm for *encryption* (there are *many* other kinds of algorithms) may be shown to be "weak", in that the key for a given encrypted document can be easily discovered, but that's not really "hacking".

Comment: @HotLicks: I agree. Bad example there. I implied that he quickly discovered a key to wriggle his way into my system. A word for that that completes the sentence?

Comment: He *broke* the code (or *broke* the algorithm, if you must).  (*Broke* is the term used by, well, "code breakers" since before WWII.)

Comment: @HotLicks: So, is it okay to say what happened was an 'algorithmic breakdown'?

Comment: No, that would not be at all idiomatic.

Comment: @JEL: I just updated the question to make it clearer what I want. No form of 'decoded' fits in the second sentence, I guess.

Comment: For the second sentence, some version of "cracked" might fit, and would be reasonably idiomatic.  (But techies will spot that you don't know what you're talking about right away.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Compromised" was the word I was searching for!

Nonetheless, the answers by @ralph.m, @JEL, @MortimerBallsack and @HotLicks also fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In programming terms, he "cracked" the algorithm.

Comment: Beat me to it. +1

Comment: That's nice! Doesn't fit my sentence though. Any synonyms? Non-programming will also work! Thanks.

Comment: How about this? "I coded an algorithm for making the system secure, but my classmate with his amateur hacking skills *cracked* it in just seven minutes" … and "What happened that day was an algorithmic *crackfest*."

Comment: @Raj It's a well-established usage in English to "crack" a code/algorithm/password/etc. See [here](http://www.tgdaily.com/business-and-law-opinion/41690-fake-itunes-cards-challenge-apples-itunes-business) for this example in context: "Earlier this week, Chinese hackers enabled
 this new 'business' by **cracking the algorithm** used to
 generate the voucher codes printed on real prepaid iTunes Gift Cards."